# Total Linear Momentum Conserved for Earth-Sun System?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, celestial-mechanics

According to 'Introductory Astronomy and Astrophysics' by Smith and Jacobs the total linear momentum of an isolated system is constant which they choose as zero, so they get (mv)1 = (mv)2.  When I apply this to the Earth-Sun system, the numbers don't add up???

Comment: Well, don't add up numbers. Write out the Lagrangian and check if linear momentum is a conserved quantity for this system first of all. Linear momentum is conserved if the system is invariant under space translation. Is it the case for your system?

Comment: The numbers depend on your choice of observer system, so why would you even expect them to add up? That the momentum of an isolated system is zero is total nonsense. It's only zero in the system of the center of mass.

Comment: Then delete it...

Comment: He can't delete it while there are upvoted or accepted answers. And the post should not be vandalized like that. If he can't get rid of and really want your name disconnected from it he can [contact the team](http://physics.stackexchange.com/contact) and ask to have it dissociated from his account.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what numbers you are using, or how much precision you are expecting, but the problem could be your assumption that the earth - sun system is an isolated system.  First there is earth's moon that (if not taken into account) might induce errors.  Then there is the effect of other planets, especially jupiter. All of these must be considered if you expect a really precise answer. Also, you do understand I assume that this relationship only pertains when the velocity measurements are made with respect to the rest frame of the system.

Answer (score 0):

First, the authors positioned their reference frame at the center of mass, if you calculate the momentums that way, the total momentum will be zero, at least instantaneously.

But that is not the point. In addition to the effects of other objects in our own solar system, mentioned in the other answer, remember that the Sun travels around the milky way center in about   225 to 250 million  years. Also there is an oscillation of the sun perpendicular to the galactic plane every about 35 million years. Thus linear momentum is not 
conserved.